# Persist ID throughout ASP.NET MVC Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

Basically I have an Image Upload controller, that I am inserting in pages as follows :-

```
    <div id='imageList'>
    <h2>Upload Image(s)</h2>
    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/File/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel(Model.Project.ProjectID));
        }  
        else
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/File/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel(0));
        }
    }
</div>
```

So I am passing an ID to the ImageUpload, in this case the ProjectID, so that I can include it in my insert.

Now this is piece of code is populating an ImageModel(id), in my case its ProjectID :-

```
    public ImageModel(int projectId)
    {
        if (projectId > 0)
        {
            ProjectID = projectId;
            var imageList = unitOfWork.ImageRepository.Get(d => d.ItemID == projectId && d.PageID == 2);
            this.AddRange(imageList);
        }
    }
```

and this in turn leads to the ImageUploadView.cshtml :-

```
<table>
@if (Model != null)
{
  foreach (var item in Model)
  {
     <tr>
        <td>
          <img src= "@Url.Content("/Uploads/" + item.FileName)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>    
 }
}
</table>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "File", new { ProjectID = Model.ProjectID }, 
       FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="description" /> 
}
```

So far so good, however my problem is that the first time

```
new { ProjectID = Model.ProjectID }
```

is correctly populated with the ProjectID, however, when I upload an image, the ProjectID is lost, and becomes zero.  Is there a way I can persist the ProjectID for the second time?

Thansk for your help and time.

*************** UPDATE *********************************************
After the upload, the Action is as follows inside the FileController :-

```
        public ActionResult Save(int ProjectID)
    {
        foreach (string name in Request.Files)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[name];

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            Image image = new Image(fileName, Request["description"]);

            ImageModel model = new ImageModel();
            model.Populate();
            model.Add(image, file);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ImageUpload");
    }
```

Comment: one thing i can think is to define a save/file/id route in your global.asax.

Comment: Hi mazhar, can you give me an example or point me to some tutorial.  Never done it before

Comment: After uploading the image are you still showing the same view? Can you post some code of the Save/File action?

Comment: @Mark thanks for the editing!  I have updated the code with the Save Action

Comment: please post the ImageUpload action as well

Comment: @Mark, the ImageUpload action is just returning a view :-         public ActionResult ImageUpload()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Project/Create.cshtml"); 
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `projectId` as a route value from the `RedirectToAction`. You should change the `ImageUpload` action to accept the `projectId`.

```
public ActionResult Save(int projectId)
{
  ....
  return RedirectToAction("ImageUpload", new { projectId = projectId });
}

public ActionResult ImageUpload(int projectId)
{
   var model = .. get the model from db based on projectId
   return View("view name", model);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try it out and let you know shortly!

Comment: Hi Mark, its not exactly working, since in the ImageUpload.cshtml, the second time, the ProjectID is 0. So when I create the Project, ID is correct, however when I do the Upload and press submit, the ProjectID is reset to 0 again, so it does not seem to be kept

Comment: R u sending the model in the return View() in ImageUpload action all the times? I think since the model is null you are getting the projectid as '0' at the second time.

Comment: Hi Mark, I was thinking of using the TempData["ProjectId"], actually already did a try and it works.  Is it ok to use the TempData, I mean its less elegant than your solution but I think its easier to use.

Comment: To reply to your question, the problem I am seeing is that the RenderPartial is not passing through the ImageUpload Action inside the FileController, so that way, I am not keeping the ProjectID